# How do you monitor the aggregate impact of fast/optimized queries that are executed with very high frequency

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

Monitoring for slow queries is pretty easy on Postgres through logging. But how does one monitor the impact of fast queries (eg less than 5ms) that in aggregate are occupying a large % of the DB load (whether IO or CPU) ?

Much like how when you profile code you don’t just care about the cost of a function but also the number of times it’s called. (Cost * Invocations)

Is there a tool that can return this data on a live workload? Lets say we have 10 types of queries. All very fast. All called many times per second. Need to know where to focus our efforts.

Thx!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html

Comment: "*All called many times per second. Need to know where to focus our efforts.*" - Once they're optimized for speed, you should focus your efforts on optimizing the process to reduce the number of calls if possible (assuming you have nothing else in your database worth optimizing). Of course process optimization will be more involved with logical changes and perhaps changes at layers other than the database itself.

Comment: @J.D. indeed. But it would be nice to get a profile of the entire landscape to know where to focus efforts.

Comment: @mustaccio interesting. Will explore this to see if it does the job

Comment: Well again, my point in optimizing the process is outside the landscape of the database, especially when you already are aware of the "*10 types of queries*" that are fast but called frequently. But I think your post has a few co-related questions, and the one you're focused on is more so for figuring out what those 10 queries are and / or the overall state of the database system. If so, then the link mustaccio provided should be helpful.

Comment: Pg_stats_statements seems perfect. Surprised I never came across it before. If one of you once to answer instead of comment I’m happy to accept there to give you points. Thx again